# Resources for Unit Testing Cocoa Applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, xcode, tdd

I'm looking into unit testing and TDD for a Cocoa desktop application and I'd like to find some code examples.

I am aware of [Chris Hanson's](http://chanson.livejournal.com/tag/unit%20testing) excellent articles, but I'd like to find through crowdsourcing some examples of actual tests in a code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CHDataStructures framework](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures) is fully unit tested by SO.com user Quinn Taylor.  It really is an excellent framework.

Edit: The framework is 99.4% unit tested: http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/coverage/source/

Answer (score 1):

Adium has [unit tests for some of its utility classes and categories](http://hg.adium.im/adium/file/700469827eee/UnitTests).